# ERROR: could not open file "base/.../...": Interrupted system call

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, eintr

After trying to run PostgreSQL 9.1 on Amazon Web Services this error has been turning up in the database and application logs. Reinstalling on a different AWS VM has not helped. Strangely the error goes a way after a few moments of activity, only to return once the system goes idle for a while.

The PostgreSQL data populating the database was recently WAL streamed from a CentOS VM and restarted as a read-write master.

Searches for "EINTR" in the PostgreSQL source turns up plenty of results, but none that jumps out as related to opening base files. Quite a few references to "could not open file". These looked promising:

```
src/backend/storage/file/copydir.c
src/backend/storage/file/fd.c 
src/port/open.c
```

Comment: That's an interesting one. Is the host OS on AWS the same as the origin OS where the basebackup was made? How was PostgreSQL installed and from where? Personally in this case I'd probably look at doing a debug-enabled PostgreSQL build then setting up 'perf' userspace probes to capture the stack at EINTR on file I/O syscalls.

Comment: No the original host was either on a VMware VM or dedicated host. I believe they're all 64-bit.